# copying text from emacs into other programs

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, emacs

Say I want to copy part of a file I'm writing in emacs into, say a blog post or something like that. Putting the text into the kill ring doesn't allow me to paste it into another program. As it stands, I have to open the same file in gedit and copy/paste from there. Is there an easier way?

[Weirdly, it works fine the other way round: copying text off a SU answer, for example, I can paste that into emacs with C-y just fine...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)      ;Make kill/yank work with the X clipboard
```

Comment: Strangely, it doesn't work for me ! I am able to copy text from gedit to emacs using C-y, but not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

It should be working. Are you running `emacs -nw` because that might prevent it from working. Try pasting into another app instead of the one you're using for blog posting (browser?) such as `gedit` and see if that works.

From the emacs manual:

> ### 26.1.2 Cut and Paste with Other Window Applications
>
> To copy text to another windowing application, kill it or save it in
>   the kill ring.  Then use the "paste" or "yank" command of the other
>   application to insert the text.
>
> To copy text from another windowing application, use its "cut" or
>   "copy" command to select the text you want.  Then yank it in Emacs with
>   `C-y' or`Mouse-2'.
>
> When Emacs puts text into the kill ring, or rotates text to the
>   front of the kill ring, it sets the "primary selection" in the window
>   system.  This is how other windowing applications can access the text.
>   On the X Window System, emacs also stores the text in the cut buffer,
>   but only if the text is short enough (the value of `x-cut-buffer-max'
>   specifies the maximum number of characters); putting long strings in
>   the cut buffer can be slow.
>
> The commands to yank the first entry in the kill ring actually check
>   first for a primary selection in another program; after that, they check
>   for text in the cut buffer.  If neither of those sources provides text
>   to yank, the kill ring contents are used.
>
> The standard coding system for X Window System selections is
>   `compound-text-with-extensions'.  To specify another coding system for
>   selections, use`C-x  x' or `C-x  X'.  *Note Communication
>   Coding::.